# ¿Cómo podría estructurar esta imagen en código html, usando bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-4

estoy intentando crear una página de inicio con bootstrap pero no he tenido suerte ya que hay dos bloques que no ocupan todo el alto que debería.

Adjunto imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Teniendo en cuenta que el color morado representa una imagen de fondo.

Por alguna razón no acaba de ocupar todo el alto y no sé como resolverlo, no tengo mucha experiencia con bootstrap.
¿cómo podría estructurarlo para conseguir este resultado?

Aqui un enlace del código: https://codepen.io/developer-context/pen/mdyjyeQ

Comment: No he podido adjuntar el código.

Comment: no entiendo que quieres

Comment: Realizar esta imagen en código html, con bootstrap

Comment: y que problema hay? usas el sistema de [columnas](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/) y lo divides

Comment: El problema es que la primera columna no ocupa todo el alto de la página, se queda hasta donde termina el último div

Comment: Debes adjuntar tu codigo para ver en que podemos ayudarte

Comment: Sin codigo poco mas podemos ayudarte, puede ser cualquier cosa, una clase css que genera conflicto, un div mal cerrado...

Comment: Acabo de adjuntar un enlace para visualizar el código.

Comment: En ese enlace, lo primero que te falta es añadir la librería, click en la rueda de css y escoger twitter-bootstrap, despues de hacer eso, siento ser tan pesado, pero no veo la duda sobre los altos, te refieres al hueco en blanco que queda debajo? [tu pen retocado](https://codepen.io/DonKaoz/pen/RwNBPVr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay unas cuantas maneras de lograr lo que necesitas, en este caso, simplemente defini una altura especifica para la fila, ya que necesitas que utilice todo el alto de la pantalla, use una altura de 100vh, ademas, aplique una regla de `align-items: stretch` para que ambas columnas de la fila principal se expandan completamente y tengan la misma altura.

```css
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5 {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  font-weight: 600;
}

.full-height {
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: stretch;
}

#main-one {
  height: auto;
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/500);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#main-two {
  background-color: white;
  height: auto;
}

p {
  font-size: 14px;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=password] {
  width: 62%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
}

.btn {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  width: 150px;
}

#terms {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#bottom-login {
  background-color: #43425D;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#bottom-sign-up {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#text-remember-me {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
}

#text-forgot-password {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
}

p {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
}

#logo-text {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

span {
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  line-height: normal;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue Light Condensed;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid" id="main">
  <div class="row full-height">
    <div class="col-md-7" id="main-one">
      <div class="row ml-4">
        <div class="col-sm-12 mt-5 mb-5">
          <h2>
            ORTHOPAEDICS E-LEARNING
          </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 mt-5">
          <h1>
            Diagnosis and Surgical Management of Orthopaedic and Trauma
          </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 mt-5">
          <h4>
            Clinical Cases in Hip, Knee and Foot & Ankle
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 mt-5 mb-5">
          <h5>In collaboration with</h5>
          <img src="{{ asset('images/Logo-AAOS-BLANCO.gif')}}" alt="" width="200px" height="95px">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5" id="main-two">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 mt-5">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
              <img src="{{ asset('images/logos/logo-KRMedicine.png') }}" alt="logo" width="111px" height="24px"> <span>Continuing Medical Education</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 mt-5">
              <p class="text-muted text-center">
                To access the elearning, please choose<br> one of the options below.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 mt-4">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <form action="#" class="text-center">
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail">
                    <br>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 mt-3">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3 text-right">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="remember-me" id="remember-me">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4" id="text-remember-me">
                  Remember me
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 text-right" id="text-forgot-password">
                  <a href="#">Forgot Password</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 mt-5">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                  <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn" id="bottom-login">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 text-left">
                  <input type="submit" value="Sign up" class="btn" id="bottom-sign-up">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 mt-5 mb-5">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                  <img src="{{ asset('images/logo-rovi.jpg')}}" alt="rovi-logo">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 mt-5">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                  <a href="#" id="terms">Legal Notice</a> | <a href="#" id="terms">Privacy Policy</a> | <a href="#" id="terms">Cookies Policy</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias ivan!! He podido comprender un poco más como funciona css entre otros.